# How to stop running the block after calling dealloc ? ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I have this code :

```
__block NSMutableArray *subCategoriesBlock = self.subCategories ;
__block UITableView *lstSubCategoriesBlock = self.lstSubCategories;
[[AsyncRequest initRequest: onCompletedBlock:^(NSMutableArray *subcategories) {
        [subCategoriesBlock addObjectsFromArray:subcategories];
        [lstSubCategoriesBlock reloadData];

    }]ExecuteRequest];
```

AsyncRequest class will send http Request on the background and then will run onCompletedBlock.

my problem:
some times the system dealloc the current view controller and then call onCompleted block, and crash on `[lstSubCategoriesBlock reloadData]` because it already deallocated.

what should I do , to prevent the system from executing `[lstSubCategoriesBlock reloadData]` when it realeasd the viewContorller ?

Comment: The `__block` is useless here -- those variables are never assigned to

Comment: @newacct could you please provide more explanation !

Comment: `__block` on a variable is only useful if the variable is being assigned to inside a block, or if the variable is being assigned to outside the block and you want the changes to be seen inside the block. Neither of those are happening here.

Comment: @newacct could you please help me in this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25548651/does-accessing-instance-variable-by-reference-safe-ios-block

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `__weak` so that when object is deallocated it points to `nil`

```
__block __weak NSMutableArray *subCategoriesBlock = self.subCategories ;
__block __weak UITableView *lstSubCategoriesBlock = self.lstSubCategories;
[[AsyncRequest initRequest: onCompletedBlock:^(NSMutableArray *subcategories) {
        [subCategoriesBlock addObjectsFromArray:subcategories];
        [lstSubCategoriesBlock reloadData];

    }]ExecuteRequest];
```