# Is accessing instance variables by reference safe?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

What is the difference between the two code snippets below:

1.

```
__block __weak NSMutableArray *arrBlock = self.arr ;
[[AsyncRequest initRequest:url onCompletedBlock:^(NSMutableArray *arr) {
         arrBlock = arr;
    }]ExecuteRequest];
```

2.

```
id __weak weakself  = self;
[[AsyncRequest initRequest:url onCompletedBlock:^(NSMutableArray *arr) {
         weakself.arr = arr;
    }]ExecuteRequest];
```

Neither of them cause retain cycles, but Apple [suggests](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW1) using the first one. Is there a problem with the second one?

Comment: it makes little sense to make `arrBlock` `__weak` in the first case

Comment: @newacct thank you , so there is no problem with the second one !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have different effects.  The first updates the local variable and the second updates the instance variable (property).

Which one you want to use depends on what you want to happen, however I suspect you want the second as the first looks like a no-op if that block is executed asynchronously.